# Getting data from a FormView's currently bound row

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a FormView with paging bound to a SqlDataSource.  I am trying to find out how to access the datasource currently bound to the FormView.  For example, if I am on page 2, how do I access the second row of the datasoure?  I only need to read certain values for comparison; the data will not be changed.  Is it possible to get this as a DataRow or DataTable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to access the DataTable in your SQLDataSource

```
    DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
    SqlDataSource mds = (SqlDataSource)MyFormView.DataSourceObject;
    DataView view = (DataView)mds.Select(args);
    DataTable dt = view.ToTable();
    DataRow dr2 = dt.Rows[1];
```

I tested this with a ListView, not a FormView, hope it works for you as well

Comment: After searching quite a bit, and trying a workaround for a while, I decided that this is pretty much the only way.  I condensed mine a little compared to your code.  My first 3 lines condensed down to `DataView view = (DataView)MySqlDataSource(new DataSourceSelectArguments());` since I just went straight to the source of the FormView.

Comment: Is there a way to get the values of my FormView when I filled the data on PageLoad without a DataSource but by passing a DataView manually in code-behind?